# looking for tcp stack implementation in c/cpp (refined)

Tags: networking, tcp

I am looking for c/c++ implementation of TCP stack (to integrate into VS2010 project).

My intent is to use it as part of a test-environment that highly intervene in tcp-stack workout and run it against another tested tcp-stack.

For example I would like to have the ability to:

1. drop specific packets
2. duplicate specific packets at specific timing
3. postpone ACK's with specific delay with/without piggyback
4. etc

Answer (score 0):

What about "lightweight IP", http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LwIP ?  It's open source under a BSD-like license.  I haven't used it, but it sounds good and I think it's around for quite some time.

BTW: I think you could accomplish any of your tasks above by using the interface of packet capture library winpcap ( http://www.winpcap.org ).  With its interface it's easy to get access to any data packet on a network card and either pass the packet on on, remove it or remove it and later insert it again (i.e. delay).  Maybe that's a much easier solution for your needs.